# Best practices for handling large data with JS fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch

Server take time (around 2min) to export a large JSON data while i got timeout error on the client side before server response.
I googled around for a bit, but I cannot find anyway to extend the timeout or continue after timeout.

```
fetch(url).then(resolve,reject);
```

Comment: Normally, you'd make the request for JSON, and it would return with a ticket ID or something similar you can poll or listen to (with more HTTP requests or websockets), and eventually download when the ticket is ready.

Comment: Maybe you should tidy your backend and reduce the payload there. If you have to get it all try to chunk it to small peaces and on client side get them one by one.

Comment: @Tan Yea this is the way Im doing right now but Im wondering if it would be a way to receive the whole data as once instead of making multi request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can do here..

1) Get the chunked data for example if you are displaying this data in a table look for something DataTables Server side processing.

2) If you still want the entire in single request then try using some db Indexing to make it faster

3) Increase Server time out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1) I am doing multi request and merge chunks in the client right now, but I want to do it in a single request. 2) The db is already indexed. 3) Yes this is exactly what i want to know, how to extend timeout amount?

Comment: Can you tell me what server side lang you are using and which web server? for example php you can use max_execution_timeOut in php.ini

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you are using fetch in node.

Try using stream to get the data in chunks. An example to this would be:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const dest = fs.createWriteStream('some/file/path');
            res.body.pipe(dest);
            res.body.on('error', err => {
                reject(err);
            });
            dest.on('finish', () => {
                resolve();
            });
            dest.on('error', err => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    });
```

You may use the stream as you wish further.

Comment: That won't help when the server takes 2 minutes to respond.